# I am not able to open my website on live serve

Tags: server, hosting, cpanel

file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\shree\storage\framework/sessions/jeTUX7NptEjvNILDa1osexDjsUoTuOgEIZ9tWaKK): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I am facing this issue and I tried every possible solutions.

Even after all possible solution I am not able to solve my error. please help me.

composer dump-autoload
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled
key gerenation
session file deletion